# Chef running from the outside

Tags: capistrano, chef-infra

is there a way to provision a server with Chef without having Ruby installed on the server that is going to be provisioned?

Basically in the same way that Capistrano is used to provision a server?

thx

ciao robertj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Chef Omnibus Installer](http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/) to install a native package for your OS including Chef Client and needed Ruby runtime packaged into one - but Ruby is always needed to be installed.

Currently Chef is not able to remotely provision a server via ssh orso.